# Adding protorpc url variables

Tags: python, google-app-engine, protorpc

Is there a way to add a variable in the protorpc service path? Similar to [webapp2 url templates](http://webapp-improved.appspot.com/guide/routing.html#the-url-template).

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for a resource container:

from https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/endpoints/getstarted/backend/write_api_post

```
ID_RESOURCE = endpoints.ResourceContainer:

MULTIPLY_METHOD_RESOURCE = endpoints.ResourceContainer(
        Greeting,
        times=messages.IntegerField(2, variant=messages.Variant.INT32,
                                    required=True))

@endpoints.method(MULTIPLY_METHOD_RESOURCE, Greeting,
                  path='hellogreeting/{times}', http_method='POST',
                  name='greetings.multiply')
def greetings_multiply(self, request):
    return Greeting(message=request.message * request.times)
```